# Css file is missing when I use .htaccess

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "/post.php?id=xxx" to "/post/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/post\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /post/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite "/section/xxx" to "/post.php?id=xxx"
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)$ /post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You've posted the contents of the .htaccess file, please also describe what's not working. The title mentions a css file - what's its URL and what happens when you try to load it?

Answer (score 0):

Because you change your root (add one level with `/post/`).
Add this line in your `post.php` HTML `<head>`:

```
<base href="/">
```

Or add the `/` before the css file name:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ... href="/css/name.css">
```